# PHP OAuth2 can't figure out how to send bearer token

Tags: php, angular, typescript, oauth-2.0, lamp

I'm setting my bearer token to be sent to the server at `api.example.com`, from `app.example.com`, like so:

```
private appendAuthHeader(headers?: Headers) {
        headers = headers || new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        let profJson = sessionStorage.getItem('profile'),
            profile: Token = this.isValidJson(profJson) ? JSON.parse(profJson) : new Token();

        if (profile && profile.access_token) {
            headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + profile.access_token);
        }
        return headers;
    }
```

It's making it into the headers fine, and works locally, but up on my production server, I get this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>401 Authorization Required</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Authorization Required</h1>
        <p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
        <p>Additionally, a 401 Authorization Required
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are my headers for the request:

```
General:
Request URL:http://api.example.com/Account/isActive
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Authorization Required
Remote Address:66.96.132.83:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
view source
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:533
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Fri, 23 Jun 2017 05:26:52 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=30
Server:Apache/2
WWW-Authenticate:Bearer realm="Service"
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.30

Request Headers:
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ca;q=0.6
Authorization:Bearer 815eb39b068354922c386e226bd0240505fd1701
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:api.example.com
Origin:http://app.example.com
Referer:http://app.example.com/login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3124.4 Safari/537.36
```

I can't quite figure out how I need to send it up for it to work on the server, any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**
It has the potential to be a cors issue as well. Here's what I get back from the get request

```
GET http://api.example.com/Account/isActive 401 (Authorization Required)

login:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.example.com/Account/isActive. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://app.example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Comment: it is more likely that the server does not accept your token, so you are obviously sending it but it is not valid

Comment: Any suggestions? Because I know the token is in the db, and matches what is being sent. I had a somewhat similar issue with sending up the login credentials, where it wouldn't see them because they were in a credentials header, rather than part of the body as a `client_id` and `client_secret`. Is it just as simple as sending the token up a different way?

Comment: @VictorRadu Also, I feel like it may be a cors thing, but I'm not sure why, because I know my server is accepting the domain I'm on, otherwise the login would fail as well. - see edit for error.

Comment: if it would have been a CORS error, the error message would look differently. Try debugging on the API end, see what headers reach the application, maybe your live server is filtering some heades